# Javascript How would i get the percentage of 2 numbers?

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

I am trying to make an xp kind of bar with javascript and how im thinking of doing this is if the required xp number is 1000, and you start with 0 of course, i need the earned xp number (0 so far or for example you have earned 20 out of 1000) to be calculated into a percentage of the 1000 so it knows how much percent of the 1000 you have earned. not just the example 20 but every number from 0 to the required amount. Sorry this is hard to explain.

Comment: (your xp * 100) / 1000

Comment: So you are asking how to do basic math? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent#Calculations

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: Rami, Felix, Mike: It is basic math but it is different to put in coding terms and is not off topic nore am i asking how to do basic math but for terms of putting it in javascript Felix. I am on the right site for this Mike and you have a kid congrats -_-

Comment: @user3833917 So you're asking how to divide and multiply a variables in javascript? Or how to get a percent from a position in a range?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this,

```
var outOff = 1000;
var value = 20;
var result = (value * 100) / outOff;
$("#divID").width( result.toString() + '%');
```